frida - How to read data from a java.lang.String array?
I have this method which has a parameter named obj of type java.lang.Object. I want to investigate its values.
My code to hook the method:
console.log(`Object type: ${obj.getClass().getName()}`);
let Arrays = Java.use('java.util.Arrays')
let arrayList = Arrays.asList(obj)
console.log(arrayList)

the printed type of obj is [Ljava.lang.String;.
but the asList call displays error:
Error: asList(): argument types do not match any of:
        .overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')

I feel weird - isn't that java.lang.String already inherit java.lang.Object?
How can I read that parameter value?

When checking for method arguments Frida doesn't seem to consider inheritance. If you just want to print the String array then see e.g. this question. Or you could force frida to use the correct method: Arrays.asList.overload('[Ljava.lang.Object;')(obj).

Thank you for replying I tried calling asList.overload as above but it still told me it needed an array Error: Expected an array, I also tried your code in the other question but it said that .overload('java.lang.CharSequence', 'java.lang.Iterable') or .overload('java.lang.CharSequence', '[Ljava.lang.CharSequence;')

seems like frida does not see the obj as an array even when I explicitly casted it to the type [Ljava.lang.String;. could this be some kind of bug? :(

String arrays are not Iterable, thus the one function can not work. Have you tried casting the array to [Ljava.lang.Object; in the code shown in your question? Also do you really need a List, may be you can simply use the array as it is (as Java[Script] array), avoiding all the array casting problems.
